# Timer stops working properly after a few seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have a tween playing every few seconds, and it works fine in the beginning, but then it starts to get jittery and resets before it even gets halfway through the tween.
Any idea why? the timer also seems to have a longer wait the first time i run the animation

```
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);

    var signalTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 0);

function move(e:Event){
    sender.x = mouseX;
    sender.y = mouseY;  

    signalTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, sendSignal);
    signalTimer.start();
}

function sendSignal(e:TimerEvent){
    signalTimer.stop();
    var sigTween1X:Tween = new Tween(signal1, "x", None.easeOut, sender.x, mic1.x, 10, false);
    var sigTween1Y:Tween = new Tween(signal1, "y", None.easeIn, sender.y, mic1.y, 15, false);

    var sigTween3X:Tween = new Tween(signal3, "x", Strong.easeIn, sender.x, mic3.x, 7, true);
    var sigTween3Y:Tween = new Tween(signal3, "y", Strong.easeOut, sender.y, mic3.y, 7, true);

}
```

Comment: I am guessing it is a cumulative effect: the ENTER_FRAME handler fires off, which adds another event listener to the signalTimer and starts it. Then when the timer goes off, it calls all those event handlers for its TIMER event which runs all the tweens.

Comment: @mitim that's what I was thinking, but is there a way to only add the listener once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a heavy segment of code; combining frame-based, timer, and tween timings.

Currently each frame calls `move()` which adds an event listener to your `signalTimer` without removing the previously added event listener:

```
signalTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, sendSignal);
```

However, adding and removing an event listener per frame is not optimal.

If you really want your timer to fire every 3-seconds, instantiate and add an event listener upon instantiation (not within the `move()` function):

```
var signalTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 0);
signalTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, sendSignal);
signalTimer.start();
```

Then don't stop the timer in `sendSignal()`.

Addressing the tweens, you could implement frame-based animation such as:

```
signal1.x -= (signal1.x - mic1.x) * 0.9;
signal1.y -= (signal1.y - mic1.y) * 0.9;
```

Therefore, implementing a delta based function to track x,y coordinates.

Comment: It seems that even if I put the timer event listener outside the move function, it still gets called everytime the frame is loaded, so what I did is put `signalTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, sendSignal);` in the sendSignal function to make it work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this frame-script called repeated on the timeline?  It should only be called once if it resides outside the scope of the `move()` function.

Comment: It's continually called, so I think it is repeated on the timeline. How do I make it not repeated?

Comment: Add `stop();` to the actions on that frame.  Maybe add a `trace("called");` statement and check the console output to see if the frame is repeated called.

Comment: I added the trace, it's outputted lots of times

Comment: I added `stop();`, and the tween now only ran once
Should it be at the end of the file?

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I hadn't gotten rid of the `removeEventListener` in the sendSignal function.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you recommend using your delta based function instead of my Tween function for the movement?

Comment: Instantiating new tweens every frame and not letting them play for their duration is heavy.  Experiment if you like, maybe trying tutorials like this [AS3 character movement, following mouse with easing](http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-character-movement-following-mouse-with-easing).